# Cannot get quantity value from webpage source code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get product in-stock counts from a webpage; the example product is as follows:

[Product link](https://www.lightinthebox.com/en/p/wosawe-men-s-cycling-jacket-windbreaker-waterproof-rain-jacket-reflective-running-jackets-bike-hooded-packable-raincoat-top-lightweight-breathable_p8747531.html?category_id=799&prm=1.2.1.48)
I did a lot of scrapping projects, but this case is new because I should get the product in the stock count too. I tried to change the value(count) to search for it and find it in the source code. I didn't find the numerical value, although. Is there any way to get the maximum of any product (this product, for example) with beautiful soup and `requests.get()`?
[image]

Comment: Did you try to look for input with the `quantity-num` class?

Comment: @Kenly Yes, I changed the value from the source code too with quantity-num. but nothing changed

Comment: I will add an answer to provide a code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will try to get the `value` attribute of an input with `quantity-num` class:

```py
r = requests.get('https://www.lightinthebox.com/en/p/wosawe-men-s-cycling-jacket-windbreaker-waterproof-rain-jacket-reflective-running-jackets-bike-hooded-packable-raincoat-top-lightweight-breathable_p8747531.html?category_id=799&prm=1.2.1.48')
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

s = soup.find('input', class_='quantity-num')

quantity = s.get('value')
```

***Update:***

To get the max quantity, look for the `div` with `quantity-select` class:

```
s = soup.find('div', class_='quantity-select')

max_quantity = s.get('data-max-quantity')
```

Comment: As I said in the question,I need the maximum quantity. For that, what to do?

Comment: The max quantity is set on the parent div